# test `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` in “subdirs.el”

Tags: load-path

In `PREFIXDIR/share/emacs/28.2/site-lisp/subdirs.el` (or something like `d:/Progs/emacs-28.2/share/emacs/28.2/site-lisp/subdirs.el` on MS-Windows):

```lisp
(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))
```

However, according to [Summary: Sequence of Actions at Startup](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html):

> When Emacs is started up, it performs the following operations:
>
> 1. It adds subdirectories to `load-path`, by running the file named `subdirs.el` in each directory in the list.
>    Normally, this file adds the directory’s subdirectories to the list, and those are scanned in their turn.
>    The files `subdirs.el` are normally generated automatically when Emacs is installed.

it seems that whether `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` is defined is an established fact that doesn't require runtime detection -- whether this function is defined when Emacs loads `site-lisp/subdirs.el` is **predictable**.

Even if `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` is somehow undefined, all subdirectories in `site-lisp` make no sense, same as `site-lisp/subdirs.el`.

---

I wonder why we need to use a runtime test here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wrote a Bash code in [Makefile.in](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/Makefile.in?h=emacs-28#n505) to generate `subdirs.el` automatically:

```bash
write_subdir=if [ -f "$${subdir}/subdirs.el" ]; \
        then true; \
        else \
          umask 022; \
          ${MKDIR_P} "$${subdir}"; \
          (echo "(if (fboundp 'normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)"; \
           echo "    (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))") \
            > "$${subdir}/subdirs.el"; \
        fi
```

for both `PREFIXDIR/share/emacs/28.2/site-lisp/` and `PREFIXDIR/share/emacs/site-lisp/` (and perhaps another several directories).

However, `PREFIXDIR/share/emacs/site-lisp/` is shared by arbitrary versions of Emacs, including those in which `normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path` is not available.

So as [the manual](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Examples.html) suggests:

> However, sometimes it happens that a function you use for customizing Emacs is not available on some platforms or in older Emacs versions. To deal with that situation, put the customization inside a conditional that tests whether the function or facility is available, like this:
>
> ```lisp
> (if (fboundp 'blink-cursor-mode)
>     (blink-cursor-mode 0))
> ```